# org.apache.commons.validator.Validator.addResource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, validation

I was update my jar commons-validator.1.1.4 to commons-validator.1.6 but i have the following error if any method is deprecated in 1.6?
i was using spring.4.3.5 and hibernate.5.1.5 jars.
I don't know why it is coming any one help to solve this error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.validator.Validator.addResource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:387)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at com.cibc.tbrm.isis.ceas.common.ui.servlet.AuthenticateServletFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthenticateServletFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at com.cibc.tbrm.isis.ceas.common.ui.servlet.WebCommonServletFilter.doFilterInternal(WebCommonServletFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at com.cibc.tbrm.isis.ceas.common.ui.servlet.JamonServletFilter.doFilterInternal(JamonServletFilter.java:59)
at com.cibc.tbrm.isis.ceas.common.ui.servlet.SelectiveFilter.doFilter(SelectiveFilter.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:270)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at com.cibc.tbrm.isis.ceas.common.ui.servlet.AccessServletFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessServletFilter.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at com.cibc.tbrm.isis.ceas.common.ui.servlet.ExceptionHandlingServletFilter.doFilterInternal(ExceptionHandlingServletFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at com.cibc.tbrm.isis.ceas.common.ui.servlet.RreCommonServletFilter.doFilterInternal(RreCommonServletFilter.java:36)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.validator.Validator.addResource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.apache.struts.validator.Resources.initValidator(Resources.java:316)
at org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorForm.validate(ValidatorForm.java:146)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processValidate(RequestProcessor.java:942)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:255)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
```

Comment: You might have two duplicate .jar files, or two different versions of the same .jar file in your classpath

Comment: No i was checked. 1.6 version only used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from the stacktrace you're using Apache Struts. A library has particular versions of dependencies they support.

[Here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cstruts%7Cstruts%7C1.2.9%7Cjar) you can see structs 1.2.9 needs commons-validator 1.1.4. It seems your new commons-validator version is not compatible with the struts version.

Either you should try updating structs version or you should rollback to earlier commons-validator version.

Comment: i'm using struts.1.2.9.jar